# Evaluating statements with negative numbers in Pascal

Tags: pascal

the following piece of code is meant to find the maximum number from a range of entered numbers. The entry is concluded once 0 is entered (0 is not taken into account when determining the maximum). It seems to be working for positive numbers but for a range of negative numbers it always says maximum is 0. Can anyone tell me where the error is?

```
program MaximumEndZero (input, output);
var
    Max,
    Value : integer;

begin
    writeln('Enter numbers');
    readln(Value);
    if (Value = 0) then
        writeln('No input')
    else
    begin
        Max := Value;
        while Value <> 0 do
        begin
            readln(Value);
            if Value > Max then
                Max := Value
        end;
        writeln('Max is: ', Max)
    end;
end.
```

Thanks vm

Comment: Consider entry -5 followed by 0 to terminate. What is the value of `Value` on each line?

Comment: And which Pascal is this? FreePascal? Delphi? GNU Pascal? Some other?

Answer (score 0):

You have created this problem by yourself by using the value of `Value` to signal the end of the program and then not taking account of this special meaning (`Value = 0`) in your code which works out which value is the maximum.

Just change your code to

```
      if (Value <> 0) and (Value > Max) then
          Max := Value
```

The `(Value <> 0) and` effectively says   "ignoring Value if it happens to be zero ..."

Comment: Hmm I don't think that's an issue here because the point is for it to exit the while loop exactly in that case (so check before every iteration if it is equal to zero). I made the mistake of putting the readln at the beginning of the loop which also ran one iteration with value = 0. not a problem if the numbers are positive but with only negative number 0 always comes out as max. Putting the readln command as the last statement in the loop fixes the problem. Thanks for your input though.

Comment: I think you are missing the point.  If you want to find the maximum value but exclude zero, then that it was you should do.  It is generally bad practice to use a special value, which the user could otherwise validly enter as data, to signal the end of an input loop.  Beginners often do it, though.

Comment: It was an exercise. Task is to terminate on 0 without including it (whichever category of practice that falls under). If you put the readln command at the end of the loop, entering 0 sets value to 0. Condition for the loop is not satisfied anymore and 0 is not included. So not sure follow what you're saying

Comment: @SanMu: the loop is exited *after* you assign 0 to Max. So 0 is very well included. Just debug your code to see what happens.

Comment: Hi Rudy, I disagree since while executes the code in the loop only AFTER the condition is met. So if you move the readln command to the end of the loop, once zero is entered there won't be anymore iterations.